# How to send binary with spring boot websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, spring-boot

In other spring platform , I used websocket to send binary message,like this:

```
  ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
  old.getBasicRemote().sendBinary(bf);
```

But with spring-boot, I make my class extends TextWebSocketHandler. But in the method `handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)` , only have param WebSocketSession and it has no method to send binary.

I try to use BinaryMessage，like this:

```
session.sendMessage(new BinaryMessage(bytes));
```

But the client side get the result as Blob(js type), I don't what to do...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use **BinaryWebSocketHandler** to handle binary message communication.

full example

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSocket
public class AppWebSocket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppWebSocket.class, args);
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyWebSocketConfigurer implements WebSocketConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addHandler(new MyTextHandler(), "/text").withSockJS();
            registry.addHandler(new MyBinaryHandler(), "/binary").withSockJS();
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyTextHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
        public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
            session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("hello world"));
        }
    }

    @Component
    public static class MyBinaryHandler extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {
        public void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) {
            try {
                session.sendMessage(new BinaryMessage("hello world".getBytes()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```